# Create a Popover in safari extension after click contextual menu

Tags: popover, safari-extension

Hi There Best Collegue,

Currently im creating a safari bookmarker and run to the following problem. I've create a Contextual menu Item and want to behave as follow:

If the user right click on a link in a page and clicks to this contextual item it should get the href attribute of this link and open a popover within there a iframe.

How can i solve this issue?

Right now i already get the href attribute but how can i open a popover?

my endscript: default.js

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleContextMenu, false);

function handleContextMenu(event){  
    if(event.target.nodeName === "A"){
        var url = event.target.href;
        safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event, url);
    }
}
```

my global.html

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event) {
if (event.command !== "DoAddSymbaloo")
        return;

        var u = event.userInfo;

}
```

How can i fix this? Tnx in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to open the link in a popover, even in an iframe within it. Safari will block it per its security policy.

Comment: @canisbos thats not correct it works on my i should maybe test it in Safari 5.0 but in 6 it works. Or Apple has to block it when i publish it.

Comment: You're right in that it is possible to load a web page in an iframe within a popover. I don't think that used to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to set the URL of a popover to a web URL (it has to be a `safari-extension` URL), but you can have a popover that contains nothing but an iframe, and tell the popover to load the URL in the iframe.

The easiest way to do this is to have a listener for "command" events in the popover itself (which you can create using either the Extension Builder or the extension API; read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingPopovers/AddingPopovers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH21-SW1) if you need a refresher).

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", function (evt) {
    if (evt.command == 'DoAddSymbaloo') {
        document.querySelector('iframe').src = evt.userInfo;
        // now let's show the popover
    }
}, false);
```

Now you have to show the popover. In order for a popover to become visible at all, it needs to be attached to a toolbar item. I'm going to assume you've already done this, using either the Extension Builder or the API. The way to show a popover programmatically is to use the `showPopover` method on its toolbar item. So first you have to find the toolbar item that you've attached the popover to. From the popover's script:

```
var myToolbarItem = safari.extension.toolbarItems.filter(function (ti) {
    return ti.popover == safari.self;
})[0];
```

This just says, "Find the toolbar item whose popover is the same as me, and assign that toolbar item to variable `myToolbarItem`."

If you wish, and if the popover will only be attached to one toolbar item, instead of assigning the found toolbar item to `myToolbarItem`, you could set it as a property of the popover object, which from the popover's point of view is `safari.self`:

```
safari.self.toolbarItem = safari.extension.toolbarItems.filter(function (ti) {
    return ti.popover == safari.self;
})[0];
```

That will provide a convenient way to get the toolbar item associated with the popover from anywhere in the script or from the global page.

Now, combining these things:

```
safari.self.toolbarItem = safari.extension.toolbarItems.filter(function (ti) {
    return ti.popover == safari.self;
})[0];

safari.application.addEventListener("command", function (evt) {
    if (evt.command == 'DoAddSymbaloo') {
        document.querySelector('iframe').src = evt.userInfo;
        safari.self.toolbarItem.showPopover();
    }
}, false);
```

(Edited for simplification of final script.)

Comment: Already solved the problem... kinda stupid i forgot that i still need the inject script :)